# Are developments considered at the end or during the whole game?

Tags: reus

For developments like "Farming community" or "Hunter community", which restrict the types of items that can be placed within the village borders, can they have had a forbidden resource at one point as long as I don't end the era with it? Or must the village have never benefited from a prohibited resource? For example, if my farming village is on the edge of water, can I place fish so long as I remove them later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the end state of the game counts. So removing them is a valid strategy yes.